# Page Doesn't Display With jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a settings page that a user is redirected to after they login.  This page seems to appar normally when there isn't jQuery Mobile, but with jQuery Mobile the page only displays header.php and footer.php.  I've looked through my code several times and I still can't find an error.  Please help me find the error and tell me why jQuery Mobile wouldn't display a page.

```
<html lang="en" class="ui-mobile ui-loading"><head><base href="http://www.example.com/user_menu.php">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
                // Navigation
                // Page
                $.mobile.page.prototype.options.headerTheme = "b";
                // Page header only
                $.mobile.page.prototype.options.contentTheme = "c";
                $.mobile.page.prototype.options.footerTheme = "b";
                // Listviews
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.headerTheme = "b";
                // Header for nested lists
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.theme = "c";
                // List items / content
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.dividerTheme = "d";
                // List divider
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.splitTheme = "c";
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.countTheme = "c";
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterTheme = "c";
                $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filterPlaceholder = "Filter data...";
                $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
            });

        </script>
        <script>
            //Disable url hash listening
            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
                $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
            });

        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/simpledialog/latest/jquery.mobile.simpledialog2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i8n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i8n.en.js"></script>
        <title>Luv Bid </title>

        <meta name="description" content="example"> <meta name="keywords" content="example">            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/style.css"><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/page_context.js"></script></head>
    <body class="ui-mobile-viewport" screen_capture_injected="true">
        <div data-role="page" data-url="/user_menu.php" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c">
            <div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-b" role="banner">
                <h1 class="ui-title" tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-level="1">Luv Bid</h1>
                <a data-role="button" data-icon="home" href="index.php" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Auctions</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home ui-icon-shadow"></span></span></a>
                <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-navbar ui-navbar-noicons" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="ui-grid-a">
                        <li class="ui-block-a">
                            <a href="index.php#about-help" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-b"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Help</span></span></a>
                        </li>
                                                <li class="ui-block-b">
                            <a data-rel="external" href="logout.php" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-b"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Logout</span></span></a>
                        </li>
                                            </ul>
                </div>
                 <a data-role="button" data-icon="gear" href="user_menu.php" class="ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Settings</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear ui-icon-shadow"></span></span></a>
                            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="ui-content ui-body-c" role="main">
<div data-role="collapsible-set" class="ui-collapsible-set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="itemwatch" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed"><div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
                <div><h3>Auction</h3><h3>Delete</h3><ul><li>&nbsp;</li></ul>    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="paymenthistory" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed"><div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
                <div>
            <h3></h3>
            <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    Payment information:                </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    Amount              </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    Type of payment             </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    Description             </li>
            </ul>
                        <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    2011-08-18 11:40:25             </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    1               </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    paypal              </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    Adding funds to account             </li>
            </ul>
                        <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    2011-08-19 12:13:03             </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    1               </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    paypal              </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    Adding funds to account             </li>
            </ul>
                        <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    2011-08-19 12:47:04             </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    1               </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    paypal              </li>
                <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                    Adding funds to account             </li>
            </ul>
                    </div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    1 |                 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div></div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="auctionwatch" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed"><div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
        <div><h3>Auction</h3><h3>Delete</h3><ul><li>&nbsp;</li></ul>        <ul><li> ipad
<a data-role="button" data-icon="delete" href="auction_watch.php?delete=ipad" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom"><span class="ui-btn-text">Delete</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow"></span></span></a>
</li></ul>      <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
            <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                <h4 class="ui-li-heading">Type in a keyword and we will e-mail you if a new auction matches the discription!</h4>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                <div>
                    Add a new item keyword              </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form action="user_menu.php?insert=true" method="post">
            <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
                <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#/user_menu.php&amp;ui-page=5-0" class="ui-link-inherit"><input type="text" size="60" name="add"><input type="submit" value="Insert" class="button"><p class="ui-li-desc">
                        </p></a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span></div></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="biddinghistory" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed"><div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
        Bids history <a name="history"></a>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Bidder              </li>
                <li>
                    Bid             </li>
                <li>
                    Date and hour               </li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
    </div></div>
    <!-- Edit Data -->
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="editdata" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed"><div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
                <form id="form" name="signup" action="user_menu.php" method="post">
                        <div>
                Username            </div>
            <div>
                examplename             <input type="hidden" name="TPL_nick" value="examplename">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="TPL_name" value="Example Name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="TPL_password" value="">
                (min 6 chars)           </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" id="repeatpassword" name="TPL_repeat_password" value="">
                (min 6 chars)           </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="TPL_email" value="emailaddress@email.com">
                            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="TPL_address" id="address" value="123 Example Street">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="city" name="TPL_city" value="Exampletopia">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="prov" type="text" name="TPL_prov" value="StateOfExamples">
            </div>
            <div>
                <select name="TPL_country">
                    <option value="">--Select here</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
<option value="United States" selected="">United States</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="zip" value="12345" name="TPL_zip" size="8">
            </div>
                        <div>
                Activate Newsletter?                <div class="ui-radio"><input type="radio" name="TPL_nletter" value="1"></div>
                Yes             <input type="radio" name="TPL_nletter" value="2">
                No              Check NO to unsubscribe to our Newsletter           </div>
                        <div>
                <input type="submit" name="Input" value="Save">
                <input type="reset" name="Input">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div></div>
    <!-- /Edit Data -->
    <!-- Add Credits -->
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="addcredits" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed"><h2 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-left" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">your balance: $ 3.00<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus ui-icon-shadow"></span></span></a></h2><div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">

         <h3>Add Funds</h3>
        <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
                        <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                $5.00
            </li>
            <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="add_funds====33==">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/payment_processing.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EN">
                    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="payments@example.com">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="324u54">
                    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="1.00">
                    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D">
                    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="srt" value="2">
                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/affiliates/plugins/payments/paypal/plugin_paypal_payments.php">

                    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                    <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>
            </li><li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                $10.00
            </li>
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="add_funds====33==">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/payment_processing.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EN">
                <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="payments@example.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="9GR2437983">
                <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="1.00">
                <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D">
                <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="srt" value="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/affiliates/plugins/payments/paypal/plugin_paypal_payments.php">

                <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
            <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
                $25.00 Bid Package
            </li>
            <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="add_funds====33==">
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.luvbid.com/payment_processing.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EN">
                <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="payments@example.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="G24AQJSQKYK7G">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="1.00">
                <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="D">
                <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="srt" value="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/affiliates/plugins/payments/paypal/plugin_paypal_payments.php">

                <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
        </ul>
    </div></div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-loading"></span><h1>loading</h1></div><div data-role="page" data-url="/user_menu.php&amp;ui-page=5-0" data-theme="c" data-count-theme="c" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c"><div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="ui-header ui-bar-b" role="banner"><div class="ui-title"></div></div><div data-role="content" class="ui-content ui-body-c" role="main"><ul class="ui-listview"><li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"> ipad
<a data-role="button" data-icon="delete" href="auction_watch.php?delete=ipad" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-link-inherit"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Delete</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow"></span></span></a>
</div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span></div></li></ul></div></div></body></html>
```

UPDATE: It seems that user_menu.php has the HTML Output it's supposed to have, but the page won't load.  I decided to instead post the HTML Output of the user_menu.php page.  Some code is cut so that I don't go over my character limit.

Comment: Do you happen to have `data-` tags for respective elements to render in `jQM`?

Comment: can you post the generated code instead? The HTML output?

Comment: instead of trying to display everything, try to display only a part of information. Try with empty template like just header, content, and footer, then add some content. Also can you post the list of JavaScript files, and the order of the files? The jquery core should precede jquery mobile.

Comment: @CaryHartline As PhillPafford asked, you really should post the HTML output of your PHP, nobody is going to check your entire PHP document for errors... By HTML output, I mean go to the page in a browser, and copy the source from there so we see what the PHP is outputting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using hash navigation outside of JQM, by chance? If so, JQM may be interfering.

Here's how you can disable it on page load or ready:

```
//Disable url hash listening
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
});
```

It may be that setting, or any number of other settings. You might try turning all default settings to off, and turning them on one-by-one to see the culprit. Shouldn't take more than a few minutes to test that. :)

Comment: I believe that JQM defaults their hash navigation capabilities to be turned on. For example, if you are already using a plugin like jquery-hashchange so that you can render pages based on a url hash extension ( e.g., www.cool.com/#hash ), JQM will probably conflict. I'll edit my answer to give an example of how to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the Ajax link loading. Add 'rel=external' to disable ajax link loading.